# Confused over job title in resume for background verification

Tags: software-industry, background-check, title

I have worked in the software industry for a total of 3 years. During this time, I worked for company 'X' who had a product called 'spark'.

My title when I joined this company was **"Spark Network Support"**. When leaving this company, there was a change in company policy and my job title was changed as **Product Implementation Executive**. In my **relieving letter** it is mentioned as **"Spark Network Support" later redesignated as "Product Implementation Executive"**. I currently hold an offer from a company for which in my **resume** I mentioned job title as **Network Support Engineer**. Is this OK, will this affect my background verification.
But in my HR round I told that the position was redesignated as Product Implementation Executive. What can be done for this

Comment: Have you tried calling the HR at your old job and asking what your position was? (this should be the same as any response given to a background check company) - and simply use that from now on - correct/explain as needed any place where you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you should be fine. To make sure, you may want to send a letter (e-mail) to the new company's HR point-of-contact explaining the discrepency.  Additionally, if you have any documents showing the company changed your title, you should send them a copy of that as well.

Comment: I have my relieving letter, where it is mentioned about the change. That should be fine I guess

Comment: Or could you just update the resume and send the newest version (explain in the email all that changed was the title due to the redesignation)